# "Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM"

Tags: smtp, office365, jakarta-mail

Trying to send mail with javamail using office 365 account getting following error (replaced my mail address and P/w)

```
 Host : smtp.office365.com,
 Port : 587
User : myMailAddress@MyDomain, 
 Pw :MyPassword
From : myMailAddress@MyDomain, To : AnotherMailAddress@MyDomain
Subject : Auto Reply:testing Log
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true

DEBUG: SMTPTransport trying to connect to host "smtp.office365.com", port 587

DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 220 LO2P123CA0023.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 12 Mar 2019 11:47:00 +0000

DEBUG: SMTPTransport connected to host "smtp.office365.com", port: 587

DEBUG SMTP SENT: EHLO LP-058
DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 250-LO2P123CA0023.outlook.office365.com Hello [1.22.231.94]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

DEBUG SMTP Found extension "SIZE", arg "157286400"
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
DEBUG SMTP SENT: MAIL FROM:<mailaddress@mydomain>
DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [LO2P123CA0023.GBRP123.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
DEBUG SMTP SENT: QUIT
```

I have email details stored in property file as follows :

```
mail.smtp=smtp.office365.com
mail.user=myMailAddress@MyDomain
mail.pwd=MyPassword
mail.port=587
```

my code is as follows  :

```java
mailProperties = new Properties();
mailProperties.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/bizsol/bizproperties/mail.properties"));
props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.host", ""+mailProperties.get("mail.smtp")); 
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");    
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port",""+mailProperties.get("mail.port")); 

final PasswordAuthentication pauth;

String x=mailProperties.get("mail.user").toString();
String y=mailProperties.get("mail.pwd").toString();

pauth = new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(x,y);

mail = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { return pauth; }                            
});

mail.setDebug(true);
msg = new MimeMessage(mail);
multi = new MimeMultipart();
BodyPart part1 = new MimeBodyPart();
part1.setText(matter);
multi.addBodyPart(part1);

msg.setFrom(fromAdd);
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,getAddresses(to));
msg.setSubject(subject);
Transport.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an extremely old version of JavaMail.  Try upgrading to the [current version](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).

Also, you can simplify your code by [getting rid of the Authenticator](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).